# ¿Cómo consultar a un mismo local storage desde diferentes sitios web?

Tags: javascript, html

necesito acceder a diferentes sitios web usando un mismo token de autenticación y autorización ya que dichos sitios web son distintas aplicaciones que pertenecen a un mismo servidor de autenticación, para colocarlos más en contexto: necesito hacer lo que hace google, una vez que inicias sesión puedes utilizar esa misma sesión para entrar en wwww.google.com, www.youtube.com, www.gmail.com, etc. Como pueden observar son dominios distintos que acceden a las mismas credenciales(token), el problema me surge en que no sé donde guardan ese token al cual acceden desde dominios distintos, no se si haya alguna forma de crear un local storage o  una cookie que pueda ser visualizada por distintos sitios web, si pueden colocarme unos códigos de ejemplo también se los agradecería.

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta. ¿Te refieres a usar datos de un sitio web determinado cuando accedes a otro sitio web **desde el mismo equipo**?

Comment: Puse el ejemplo de google para que se entienda, estoy manejando tres aplicaciones web (SPA) de distintos dominios que pertenecen a un mismo ecosistema (como el ejemplo de google), necesito que con solo iniciar sesión en alguna de las tres aplicaciones pueda usar esa misma sesión en el resto de aplicaciones, para que el usuario no tenga que loguearse tres veces (una en cada aplicación), mi pregunta es como puedo GUARDAR un token que se pueda COMPARTIR en tres webs DISTINTAS

Comment: al iniciar sesión en un dominio se hace contra un servidor de autenticación, el servidor de autenticación setea una cookie (autologin o loged in en el dominio del servidor de autenticación) y responde con un token valido para el dominio autenticado (token local), cada dominio que no tenga un token local intenta un autologin contra el servidor de autenticacion, si la cookie es válida (del auth server) este responde con un token especifico de ese dominio (cookie del dominio/app)

Comment: Y esa cookie que devuelve el servidor una vez que la reciba una mis aplicaciones, como hago para consultarla desde otra, alguien podría darme un ejemplo básico en javascript? de una misma cookie consultada por dos webs distintas

Comment: @Antalvpro lo que quieres hacer se llama **[`Single Sign-on`](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_Sign-On)** y el tema es muy amplio para una sola pregunta/respuesta

Comment: Como lo indica @KacosPro, existen muchas formas. La implementación de tu frontend es la encargada de trabajar con el `token` o `cookie`. Además si las páginas SPA que mencionas corresponden a un mismo ecosistema, deben compartir entonces el mismo sistema de autenticación. Si no lo hacen, pues ya eso es un problema.

Comment: Como en tu pregunta estableces que se usa el mismo servidor de autenticación. Entonces debes verificar en tu frontend cómo se está almacenando el `token` o la `cookie`. ¿Cuál es el problema específico que estas presentando?

Comment: si @KacosPro , se que es Single Sign-on, se tambien que necesito un servidor de autenticación, todo eso lo sé, pero mi pregunta es como guardo una cookie o un localstorage que pueda ser consultado por distintos frontend (ya que esa es la cookie que tendrá el token)

Comment: No podes acceder a cookies/localstorage entre dominios. Cada dominio tiene sus cookies/sesiones el login se maneja via tokens que residen en esas sesiones. Estos tokens se generan y van firmados por una misma clave secreta que reside en el lado de los servidores (hmac/jwt).
En SPAs la cookie del SSO se genera/lee/valida al hacer un get de un jsonp o img. La mecánica es simple pero un poco engorrosa de aplicar, sugiero buscar una librería SSO que te de las herramientas para montar el server y configurar los clients/brokers/servers según el lenguaje de servidor que uses.